# Access cross origin image data

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've a site page  from  `www.example.com/url1`:

```
<html>
<body>
    <img src="http://differentsite.com/file.jpg" />  
</body>
</html>
```

How can I access the image data thru content script or the background script  as I'm getting this error?:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on
>   'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by
>   cross-origin data.

Comment: Add that site to `"permissions"` in manifest.json

Comment: already present  `"http://*/*", "https://*/*"` in the permissions

Comment: There's something else wrong in your code I guess. See the existing answers like [Canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data via local chrome:// extension URL](//stackoverflow.com/q/19894948)

Comment: I''ve already referenced this url, and it seems I'm really able to access the image pixels using the accepted answer.